# Child process doesn't execute function after first iteration

Tags: c, pthreads, fork

**Program Design**

My program is designed so that there are 6 child processes created. Each child process will create 3 threads. So, there should be 18 total threads.

When I create a child process, it calls a function called createThread and passes it the childIndex of that iteration (ie, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5).

When the function is executed, it should:

1. Store the child PID into the pid element in the struct childThreads.
2. Go into a for loop and create a thread 3 times and store it's thread ID in the tid element of the same struct
3. Print out the results just to make sure everything is working.

**My issue:**

When the child index is at it's first iteration (ie. 0) the output is as expected.
However, at the next iteration to the last, the function stops executing halfway.

**Expected output:**

```
childThread[0].pid = 1111
childThread[0].tid[0] = 0
childThread[0].tid[1] = 1
childThread[0].tid[2] = 2

childThread[1].pid = 2222
childThread[1].tid[0] = 0
childThread[1].tid[1] = 1
childThread[1].tid[2] = 2
...
..
.
```

**Actual Output:**

```
childThread[0].pid = 1111
childThread[0].tid[0] = 0
childThread[0].tid[1] = 1
childThread[0].tid[2] = 2

childThread[1].pid = 2222
childThread[2].pid = 3333
childThread[3].pid = 4444
childThread[4].pid = 5555
childThread[5].pid = 6666
```

**My Code**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>

int numChild = 6;
int numThreadsPerChild = 3;

struct childAndThreads {

    pid_t pid;
    pthread_t *tids;
};

struct childAndThreads *childThread;
pid_t *pids;

void createThreads(int i) {

    int childIndex = i;
    childThread[childIndex].pid = getpid();

    printf("childThread[%d].pid = %d\n", childIndex, childThread[childIndex].pid);

    for(int i = 0; i < numThreadsPerChild; i++) {

        childThread[childIndex].tids[i] = i;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < numThreadsPerChild; i++) {

        printf("childThread[%d].tid[%d] = %d\n", childIndex, i, i);
    }
}

int main() {

    pids = malloc(numChild * sizeof(pid_t));

    childThread = malloc(numChild * sizeof(struct childAndThreads));
    childThread->tids = malloc(numThreadsPerChild * sizeof(pthread_t));

    for(int i = 0; i < numChild; i++) {

        switch(pids[i] = fork()) {
            case 0:
                createThreads(i);
                return 0;
            case -1:
                printf("Fork Error\n");
                break;
            default:
                //I am a parent
                break;
        }
     }

    for(int i = 0; i < numChild; i++) {
        wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to the actual answer, I note that the code does not actually create any threads. Not sure whether you just left that out to simplify the code for SO though.

Comment: @kaylum Yeah, it was just to simplify the question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
childThread->tids = malloc(numThreadsPerChild * sizeof(pthread_t));
```

That line is not correct. It only allocates `tids` for the first child process. Instead it should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numChild; i++) {
    childThread[i].tids = malloc(numThreadsPerChild * sizeof(pthread_t));
}
```